# IndexError: index is out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a program to increase the size of an image file by using image quilting. However, when finding the minimum cost (findMinHorzCost function), I am getting an IndexError saying the index is out of bounds and I'm not entirely sure where in the function the error lies.

```
def getHorzCost(self, imagePixel, samplePixel):
    horzCost = np.zeros((overlapWidth, patchSize), np.int)
    for i in range(overlapWidth):
        for j in range(patchSize):
            if j == patchSize - 1:
                horzCost[i, j] = self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j), imagePixel, samplePixel)
            elif i == 0:
                horzCost[i, j] = self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j), imagePixel, samplePixel) + min(self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel), self.colourCorrection((i + 1 - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel))
            elif i == overlapWidth - 1:
                horzCost[i, j] = self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j), imagePixel, samplePixel) + min(self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel), self.colourCorrection((i - 1 - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel))
            else:
                horzCost[i, j] = self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j), imagePixel, samplePixel) + min(self.colourCorrection((i - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel), self.colourCorrection((i + 1 - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel), self.colourCorrection((i - 1 - overlapWidth, j + 1), imagePixel, samplePixel))
    return horzCost

def findMinHorzCost(self, horzCost):
    Bound = np.zeros((patchSize), np.int)
    Matrix = np.zeros((overlapWidth, patchSize), np.int)
    for j in range(1, patchSize):
        for i in range(overlapWidth):
            if i == 0:
                Matrix[i, j] = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i + 1, j - 1] else i + 1
            elif i == overlapWidth - 1:
                Matrix[i, j] = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i - 1
            else:
                currentMin = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i - 1
                Matrix[i, j] = currentMin if horzCost[currentMin, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i + 1
            horzCost[i, j] += horzCost[Matrix[i, j], j - 1]
    minimum = 0
    for i in range(1, overlapWidth):
        minimum = minimum if horzCost[minimum, patchSize - 1] < horzCost[i, patchSize - 1] else i
    Bound[patchSize - 1] = minimum
    for j in range(patchSize - 1, 0, -1):
        Bound[j - 1] = Matrix[Bound[j], j]
    return Bound
```

The error that shows in the console is this:

> Matrix[i, j] = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i + 1, j - 1] else i + 1
>   IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

I believe the index which is causing the error is Matrix[i] as when I change the overlapWidth variable, the size of the index in the error changes.

Comment: Axis 1 means the problem is j.

Comment: What are the values of `patchSize` and `overlapWidth`, and what is the dimension of `horzCost` @lalale

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh when I tested the program to get the error above, patchSize was 15 and overlapWidth was 10. horzCost is a tuple.
    horzCost = np.zeros((overlapWidth, patchSize))

Comment: horzCost is a tuple of what dimensions? @lalale

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh horzCost.shape gives me (15, 10)

Comment: You need to adjust the shape of `Matrix` to match `horzCost` and adjust the range variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by OP in his comments, the shape of `horzCost` is `(15,10)`  but the shape of `Matrix` is `(10,15)` which is causing the `IndexError`

In addition you need to use `overlapWidth` instead of `patchSize` after the double for loops

```
patchSize = 15
overlapWidth = 10
Bound = np.zeros((patchSize), np.int)
Matrix = np.zeros((overlapWidth, patchSize), np.int)
horzCost = np.zeros((patchSize, overlapWidth), np.int)
print(Matrix.shape)
#(10, 15)
print(horzCost.shape)
#(15,10)
```

So the shape of the `Matrix` needs to change to match the shape of `horzCost`, or vice-versa, according to the needs.

In addition, `j` should run till `overlapWidth` and `i` should run till `patchSize` as well  or vice-versa according to the needs

In addition
So the code will change to

```
def findMinHorzCost(self, horzCost):

    Bound = np.zeros((patchSize), np.int)

    # Fixed the dimensions to patchSize x overlapWidth
    Matrix = np.zeros((patchSize, overlapWidth), np.int)

    # Fixed the range stop to overlapWidth
    for j in range(1, overlapWidth):
        # Fixed the range stop to patchSize
        for i in range(patchSize):
            if i == 0:
                Matrix[i, j] = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i + 1, j - 1] else i + 1
            elif i == overlapWidth - 1:
                Matrix[i, j] = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i - 1
            else:
                currentMin = i if horzCost[i, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i - 1
                Matrix[i, j] = currentMin if horzCost[currentMin, j - 1] < horzCost[i - 1, j - 1] else i + 1
    minimum = 0
    for i in range(1, overlapWidth):
        minimum = minimum if horzCost[minimum, overlapWidth - 1] < horzCost[i, overlapWidth - 1] else i
    Bound[overlapWidth - 1] = minimum
    for j in range(overlapWidth - 1, 0, -1):
        Bound[j - 1] = Matrix[Bound[j], j]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the error I was having, however now I'm having an error on the line:  
`minimum = minimum if horzCost[minimum, patchSize - 1] < horzCost[i, patchSize - 1] else i ` 
The error that comes up is: IndexError: index 14 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
Have I just made the same mistake here?

Comment: Yes, I replaced `patchSize` to `overlapWidth` and now the code should work well!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've made these changes to the code and now the program just crashes when it gets to this function

Comment: What I tried to explain here is a way to make the functions not fail, by making the values of `patchSize` and `overLapWidth` consistent, along with dimensions of some arrays, now you can expand on that idea and make changes to make all variables consistent so as to avoid other errors, which might occur outside the function! Does that make sense @lalale

Comment: I've edited the main post to include the function to create the horzCost tuple. As far as I can tell, they should both be getting set to the same values, however one is being set to (15, 10) and the other to (10, 15).

Comment: Also what does crashing means, what errors are you gettting now? Can you debug a bit further on your own line by line in both functions, and see where the issue is happening? Also as per my answer `So the shape of the Matrix needs to change to match the shape of horzCost, or vice-versa, according to the needs.
In addition, j should run till overlapWidth and i should run till patchSize as well or vice-versa according to the needs` So try both combinations to ensure your code works fine! @lalale

Comment: When I say crashing, the program almost immediately becomes unresponsive and doesn't do anything after the function is called

Comment: Then it might be something outside the two functions you mentioned, And it might also be outside the scope of the question asked, which was suggestions on getting rid of the `IndexError` which we were able to achieve. I apologize if I am unable to help you any further @lalale I am sure if you play around with mentioned parameters, and do further debugging, you should be able to resolve the issue!

Comment: I did a bit of googling and I added the line of code `horzCost[i, j] += horzCost[Matrix[i, j], j - 1]` which combined with the changes you suggested, stopped the program from immediately becoming unresponsive which leads me to believe it was just stuck in an endless loop. However now when I run the program, it will sometimes go through the loop 2-5 times before getting the error "IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15" and sometimes the error will appear immediately. I appreciate all the help you've given me so far and I understand if you wish to help someone else :)

Comment: Yes, so you are debugging now, I would suggest to continue further debugging with print statements, or debug using an IDE like PyCharm to make your life easy, I am sure you will be able to get it solved! Sorry If I am not able to help you further!